# Laravel add multiple data to pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

[image]

```
PIVOT TABLE

| post_id | food_id | post_gram |
|:----    |:------: | -----:    |
| 1       | 5       | NULL      |
| 1       | 6       | NULL      |
| 1       | 20      | NULL      |
```

Hi, I have a table **Post** and **Food** and pivot table **food_post**, when I want to save data to the pivot table it saves only post id and food id but post_gram dont(it sets value to NULL).. in **blade** I have select input to select food **select=name"select2[]"** and input to write how many grams **select=name"select3[]"** and then a button that duplicates it so that the user can add how much food he wants , **I need that when saving data to the pivot table the value of grams is saved and there is no null in db**, in model i define "withPivot" i have also try attach() and it throws error that say "Array to string conversion"

```
---------------**BLADE** ----------------
<div class="flex my-5" id="duplicater">

       <select name="select2[]"  id="select">
           <option disabled selected>Vyberte prosím potravinu</option>
           @foreach ($food as $f )
           <option value="{{$f->id}}">{{$f->nazev}}</option>
           @endforeach
       </select>

       <div>
           <input id="food" type="text" name="select3[]" value="" placeholder="Počet gramů">
       </div>
   </div>

   </div>

<button type="submit" class="uppercase mt-15 bg-gray-900 text-gray-100 text-lg font-bold py-4 px-20 rounded-2xl ">Submit Post</button>
</form>
<button id="button" class="p-3 my-6 border-green-400 border text-green-400" onclick="duplicate()">Přidat další potravinu</button>
```

```
--------------**Post Controller**----------------

public function store(Request $request)
   {
       //dd($request->select2);
       $data = [];

       $request->validate([
           'title' => 'required',
           'description' => 'required',
           'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
       ]);

       $newImageName = uniqid() . '-' . $request->title . '.' . $request->image->extension();

       $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);



       $post = new Post();
       $post->title = $request->input('title');
       $post->description = $request->input('description');
       $post->slug = SlugService::createSlug(Post::class, 'slug', $request->title);
       $post->image_path =$newImageName;
       $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

       $post->save();
         

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         -----------here is the attach to the pivot table -------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           $post->food()->sync($request->select2,[
       'post_gram' => $request->select3
           ]);


       return redirect('/blog')
           ->with('message', 'Your post has been added!');
   }
```

-------------------------post model----------------------------

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Laravelista\Comments\Commentable;

class Post extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
   use Sluggable;
   use Commentable;


       protected $fillable = ['title','slug' ,'description' , 'image_path', 'user_id'];

   public function user(){
           return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
   public function food(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class)->withPivot('post_gram');//->withPivot(['post_kalorie','post_bilkoviny','post_sacharidy','post_tuky','post_objem']);
   }
   public function sluggable():array{
       return[
           'slug'=>[
               'source' => 'title'
           ]
       ];
   }
}
```

Comment: you need to change `post_objem` to `post_gram` in controller and model too

Answer (score 0):

The column name is `post_gram`

In model

Change

```
public function food(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class)->withPivot('post_objem');
}
```

To

```
public function food(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class)->withPivot('post_gram');
}
```

And in controller

use `sync` helper as below

```
$post->food()->sync([$request->select2,$request->select3]);
```

OR

use `attach` helper as below

```
$post->food()->attach([$request->select2,$request->select3]);
```

Comment: Hi, i change model and controller to post_gram and still nothing ://

Comment: Can you show model of pivot table?

Comment: `<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FoodPost extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
`

Comment: use `sync` helper as per my edited answer. please check

Comment: i try it, but it throws error ` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `food_post` (`food_id`, `post_id`, `0`) values (0, 55, 9)) `

Comment: i also try  $post->food()->sync(['food_id'=>$request->select2,'post_gram'=>$request->select3]); but it still throw same error

Comment: try using `attach()`

Comment: still same error ://